# Model of Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

How can I use index function of model in controller ??

As per codeigniter user guide we know we can use

```
$this->name_of_model->function_of_model();
```

in controller. In redirection we can use

```
redirect('controller_name/function_name');
```

if we use index function in controller then we can use in redirection

```
redirect('controller_name');
```

to redirect to that controller. In this way how can I use

```
$this->name_of_model->function_of_model();
```

this syntax.

Thanks

Comment: unable to understand .... You want to redirect to model ?

Comment: No, I would like to know if I use index function in model,then how can I specify that in this syntax `$this->name_of_model->function_of_model();`

Comment: I can't imagine why you'd want a default function in a model, models are loaded with function names for a reason, so you know exactly what they're doing. I think you may want to take some time to watch a few CI tutorials and get a feel for their MVC concepts.

Answer (score 0):

Let suppose you are calling a model index in controller index

```
Class test_controller extends CI_Controller
{
   function index(){

       $this->load->model('model_name');      
       $this->model_name->model_index();      

   }
}
```

Now when ever you redirect to Controller index the model index will be called automatically.

EDITS:
How ever , you can use it like this

```
Class test_controller extends CI_Controller
{
   function index(){

       $query = $this->db->get('my_table');
       $data['query_result'] = $query->result();  

   }
}
```

And model index is this

```
function index()
{
  $query = $this->db->get('my_table');
  return $query->result();
}
```

You should note model index is not called here instaed model has been useless we are doing work without it. So seperating the database interaction is usefull and combining it with controller breaks the MVC pattren.

Comment: Can I use like below 
`Class test_controller extends CI_Controller
{
   function index(){

       $this->load->model('model_name');      
       $this->model_name();      

   }
}`

or 

`Class test_controller extends CI_Controller
{
   function index(){

       $this->load->model('model_name');      
       $this->model_index();      

   }
}`

Comment: no this is not possible the correct way is how i told you see my edits.

Answer (score 0):

```
class User_model extends CI_Model
{
    function __construct()
    {

        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->database();
    }

    function insertrow($data,$table){

        $this->db->insert($table,$data);
    }

    function updaterow($data,$table,$id){
        $this->db->where($id);
        $this->db->update($table,$data);
    }

    function fetchrow($table){

        $query = $this->db->get($table);
        return $query->result();

     }

     function fetchrowedit($tbl_name,$id){

    $query = $this->db->get_where($tbl_name, $id); 

    return $query->result();
    }


    function fetchrowlogin($info,$table){

        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->where($info);
        $this->db->from($table);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        if($query->num_rows() > 0){
        $row = $query->row_array();
            return $row;
        }
    }


        function alreadyexits($table,$var){
        $query = $this->db
        ->select('*')
        ->where($var)
        ->get($table)
        ->num_rows();
        return $query;
        }

        function isVarExists($table,$var){
        $query = $this->db
        ->select('*')
        ->where($var)
        ->get($table)
        ->num_rows();
        return $query;
            }

    function messages_list($ids){

        $this->db->where('reciver_id', $ids);
        $this->db->limit(10);
        $this->db->order_by("time", "asc");
        $this->db->from('message_table');
        $query = $this->db->get(); 
        return $query->result();
    }
}
```